# Calculate the module of complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have the following complex number:

Z = $(1+i)^{3}$ = $(1+i)$ + $(1+i)$ + $(1+i)$

And = 1 + 1i + 1i + i${^2}$ + 1 + 1i + 1i + i${^2}$ 1 + 1i + 1i + i${^2}$

$$|6 + 6i| = \sqrt{6^2 + 6^2} = \sqrt{36 + 36}=\sqrt{72}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: $x^3$ means $x\cdot x\cdot x$, not $x+x+x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all! Sorry.

The notation $x^3$ means $x\cdot x\cdot x$, not $x+x+x$ that would be $3x$.

Since $(1+i)^2=(1+2i-1)=2i$, we have $(1+i)^3=(1+i)^2(1+i)=2i(1+i)=-2+2i$. Thus
$$
|(1+i)^3|=|-2+2i|=\sqrt{4+4}=\sqrt{8}
$$
Alternatively, use $|z^3|=|z|^3$. Since $|1+i|=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}$ you of course get at the same result.

You can also use the binomial expansion $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$, so
$$
(1+i)^3=1^3+3\cdot 1^2\cdot i+3\cdot 1\cdot i^2+i^3=
1+3i-3-i=-2+2i
$$

Comment: But +3i -i is not = to -2i?  why the result is = -2 +2i?

Comment: @devtreat $3i-i=2i$, how can it be $-2i$?

Answer (score 0):

(since  $\left| { z }^{ n } \right| ={ \left| z \right|  }^{ n }$)  it should be $$\left| z \right| =\left| (1+i)^{ 3 } \right| ={ \left| 1+i \right|  }^{ 3 }={ \left( \sqrt { 1+1 }  \right)  }^{ 3 }=2\sqrt { 2 } $$ 
and it is wrong to write ${ a }^{ 3 }\neq a+a+a$